# How to create a simple custom function in R

Tags: r, dplyr, predict, gam, custom-function

I have a tree growth database containing the number of cells in the 'enlarging' growth stage for every DOY (Day of the year) for every tree and every year (in this example: 2 different trees per year, 2 years). I went to the field to take samples every few weeks as you can see. The database looks like this (simplified):

```
df <- data.frame("Year" = c(2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012,2012,
                            2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013,
                            2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013),
  "Tree" = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 41, 41,
             41, 41, 41, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53),
  "DOY" = c(65, 97, 125, 177, 214, 65, 97, 125, 177, 214,
            61, 99, 118, 166, 221, 61, 99, 118, 166, 221),
  "Enlarging" = c(0, 2, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3, 6, 3, 1, 0, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 7, 5, 2))


df <- df %>%
  mutate(Year = as.factor(Year),
         Tree = as.factor(Tree),
         DOY = as.numeric(DOY),
         Enlarging = as.numeric(Enlarging))


print(df)
   Year Tree DOY Enlarging
1  2012   15  65         0
2  2012   15  97         2
3  2012   15 125         4
4  2012   15 177         5
5  2012   15 214         2
6  2012   22  65         1
7  2012   22  97         3
8  2012   22 125         6
9  2012   22 177         3
10 2012   22 214         1
11 2013   41  61         0
12 2013   41  99         3
13 2013   41 118         4
14 2013   41 166         3
15 2013   41 221         1
16 2013   53  61         2
17 2013   53  99         4
18 2013   53 118         7
19 2013   53 166         5
20 2013   53 221         2
```

I would like to apply a GAM function to understand the growth curves of the enlarging growth stage.
After the applying the GAM, I want to obtain **DAILY** predictions (from the first day of samplings until the last day) about when does this growth stage start and finish for every tree, every year. For that, I wanted to create a simple function (called `gamfun` in this case) that applies the model and the prediction for every tree and returns the fitting:

```
gamfun <- function(Year, Tree){
  
#create the gam model

  enlarging_model <- gam(Enlarging ~ s(DOY), data = df, quasipoisson, gamma = 1, min.sp = 1)
  
  new_DOY <- seq(min(datosSTD$DOY), max(datosSTD$DOY), 1) #create daily sequence for day of the year

#predict daily growth base on the previous model
  
  enlarging_pred <- as.vector(predict(enlarging_model, data.frame(new_DOY), type="response"))
  
  fit <- data.frame(cbind(DOY=DOY, enlarging_pred = enlarging_pred))
  return(fit)
}

#Apply this model and predictions for every tree of every year

Table <- (as.data.frame(mapply(gamfun, Year=df$Year,Tree=df$Tree,
                                 SIMPLIFY = TRUE, USE.NAMES=TRUE)))
```

Basicly I want to get the predicted value (fitting) for the number of cells every day of the year, but I end up getting errors, I assume because my syntax is not good, but I really don't know how to write it correctly. At this point I'm getting as an output a dataframe containing thousands of colums (called V1, V2...V1260) with 2 rows (DOY and enlarging) each. In the prediction row the values seem to be repeat themselves every column. Something like this:

```
                     V1                          V2
DOY            c(59, 60, 61,  [...]          c(59, 60, 61,  [...]
enlarging_pred c(0.0337, 0.0363, [...]       c(0.0337, 0.0363, [...]
```

I think my syntax error might be at the end, when trying to get the Table output. My real database is more complex, 6 trees instead of 2, and 10 years instead of 2 too, 4 growth stages instead of 1. So I really need an efficient way to apply the gam model and get the daily predictions for that amount of trees and years.

Hope someone can help me, I'm really stuck. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you share what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @novica I just added the last output I'm getting at the end of my question. It's not exactly an error.

Comment: This would be easier (and likely statistically more efficient) if you fitted one model to all trees, years, and growth stages... But one thing that's wrong is that when you do `data = data.frame(new_DOY)` that data frame *doesn't* include a variable named `DOY` and hence you get back the fitted values of the data used to fit the model. Your `gamfun` isn't using `year` anywhere.